# I have that error"#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'"

Tags: mysql, collation

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_methods` (
  `payment_method_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`payment_method_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE payment_methods 
    ( payment_method_id tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY (payment_method_id) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

NOTE: COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci replace with COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci

REFER: https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolved-when-i-faced-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci-error/#.X2jHBGgzZPY

Answer (score 8):

utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci is a collation that is new in MySQL 8.0

It is not recognized in earlier versions of MySQL, for example 5.7.

It may also not be recognized in forks of MySQL such as MariaDB.

You should only use that collation in MySQL 8.0.

Consult documentation for the version of software you are using to see the set of supported collations.

For example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html

Or query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS` to find the list.

Comment: Or `SHOW COLLATION;`