# "COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'"

Tags: mysql

I am not an expert in mysql I have looked in other posts for the solution to this problem but I cannot solve it, could someone help me to solve this problem?

I'm migrating a web and when I import the database I get this error.

thanks a lot

Comment: `SHOW COLLATION WHERE CHARSET = 'utf8mb4';` - this is complete collations list which can be used with UTF8MB4 charset on your server.

Comment: *when I import the database I get this error* Check the dump. Does CREATE DATABASE stmt is present? Does the charset is specified in all CREATE statements?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the collation of the database(where you are importing) to utf8mb4

[image: See here]

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here: [I have that error"#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995271/i-have-that-error1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-0900-ai-ci)

NOTE: `COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` replace with `COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it very easy fix. Make sure you backup your database before, just in case you need to change to another collation. Go to PHPMYADMIN, select the database, and hit OPERATIONS, there at the end, find COLLATION select a collation what will work for you 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' for example, then check both 'Change all tables collations' and 'Change all tables columns collations' hit GO. My database worked perfectly.

Comment: This question does not mention PHP, so I'm not sure that PHPMYADMIN would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing your database from the file, you can use the following workaround with `sed` command to correct it:

```
sed 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8_general_ci/g;s/utf8mb4/utf8/g' file.sql > newfile.sql
```

If you're using `ddev`, here is the example of usage:

```
zcat file.sql.gz | sed 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8_general_ci/g;s/utf8mb4/utf8/g' | ddev import-db
```