# MariaDB utf8mb4_0900_as_cs collation error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

I'm trying to switch to MariaDB from mysql 8. I downloaded latest MariaDb 10.10.1 RC version, trying to import backup created from mysql using mysqldump and I get the following error
`Unknown collation 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs'`

What is the equivalent collation in MariaDB. Since this question has been closed due to similar question already answered. Similar question is about `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` which is different than what asked here and there is no answer about the collation that I asked. So I would please don't close it again

Comment: For most applications, you can change to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` and get the same results.  (I checked all western European characters.)  That requires editing the dump file.

Comment: See also `utf8mb4_bin` if you can't wait for 10.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MariaDB-10.10.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10100-release-notes/) has UCA 14.0.0 collations, newer than MySQL's UCA 9.0.0 collations (finally), which are a result of [MDEV-27009](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27009).

So the equivalent collation is `uca1400_as_cs`.

Note: 10.10.2 GA is coming very soon.

Comment: Great!!! Do you know when?

Comment: what about character set. using utf8mb4 in mysql. what is the equivalent to MariaDb?

Comment: When? At most a few days. MariaDB character sets are the same as MySQL's currently.

Comment: Slightly later than expected, but [10.10.2 is GA and released](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10-10-2-release-notes/) now.

Answer (score 1):

(Reopened because the dup ([I have that error"#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995271/i-have-that-error1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-0900-ai-ci)) referred to only 5.7.)

MariaDB does not (yet) have the equivalent of Unicode's 9.0.0; they are still on 5.2.0.

For most applications, you can change to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci and get the same results. (I checked all western European characters.)

Unfortunately, that requires editing the dump file. –

Comment: See [danblack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370921/1766831) for what to do in MariaDB 10.10.