Can't install python's mariadb connector
I am on arch linux system.
I am using a virtual environment created using:
python -m venv .venv


I wanted to connect to mariadb using python. 
Firstly using "mysql-connector-python", but it had some issues.
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Then I tried to download mariadb connector using:
source .venv/bin/activate
pip3 install mariadb

I am getting this error and can't seem to find any way out
Collecting mariadb==1.0.11
  Downloading mariadb-1.0.11.zip (85 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mariadb
  Building wheel for mariadb (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mariadb (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [36 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb
      copying mariadb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb
      copying mariadb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/INDICATOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/CURSOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/constants
      running build_ext
      building 'mariadb._mariadb' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb
      gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=11 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I./include -I/home/anand_maurya/Documents/SchoolProject/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c mariadb/mariadb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/mariadb/mariadb.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR=\"/usr/lib/mysql/plugin\"
      mariadb/mariadb.c: In function ‘PyInit__mariadb’:
      mariadb/mariadb.c:155:35: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        155 |     Py_TYPE(&MrdbConnection_Type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                                   ^
      mariadb/mariadb.c:168:31: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        168 |     Py_TYPE(&MrdbCursor_Type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                               ^
      mariadb/mariadb.c:174:29: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        174 |     Py_TYPE(&MrdbPool_Type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                             ^
      mariadb/mariadb.c:180:34: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        180 |     Py_TYPE(&MrdbIndicator_Type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                                  ^
      mariadb/mariadb.c:186:38: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        186 |     Py_TYPE(&Mariadb_Fieldinfo_Type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                                      ^
      mariadb/mariadb.c:192:38: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        192 |     Py_TYPE(&Mariadb_DBAPIType_Type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                                      ^
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mariadb
Failed to build mariadb
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (mariadb)

Any feedback will be appreciated.

About the collation https://stackoverflow.com/a/63995755/5320906

Thanks, now mysql.connector works too

I find it very difficult to get mariadb connector installed :-(  I usually just use one of the MySQL connection packages.

MariaDB Connector/Python 1.0.x branch is not maintained anymore - use 1.1.x instead.
If you want to use old 1.0.11 version you need also an older Python version. Supported Python versions for MariaDB Connector/Python 1.0.11 are defined in setup.py:
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',


To be fair to the OP, I have an Arch machine and 1.1.10 won't install on it https://pastebin.com/kfLFeW0b

@snakecharmerb corrected https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python/commit/3d34bb6880c65eea4f736c85005aa0700124918e ready for next release
